# how to put text above input on focus and on typing(styled component)

Tags: css, reactjs, input, styled-components

I tried to move text above input on focus and on typing ,I succeeded on focus but I could'nt achieve that on typing , when I move the text back to the text place(like the image that I upload below)
this my code

```
export const InputGroup = styled.label`
    margin:1rem 0;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    
`;

export const InputLabel = styled.span`
    padding:0;
    pointer-events: none;
    position:absolute;
    transition: 0.2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1);
    margin-top: 0;
    
`;

export const InputField = styled.input`
  
  padding: 16px 0;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;


  &:focus
  {
    border: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    outline:0;
  }

  &:valid + ${InputLabel}
  {
    top: 17px;
    font-size:1rem;
    color: #8d8d8d;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    
  }

  &:focus + ${InputLabel}
  {
    opacity:1;
    transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-150%) translateX(-20px);
    font-size:1.2rem;
  }

 
`;


          <InputGroup>
            <InputField placeholder=' ' />
            <InputLabel>Full Name</InputLabel>
          </InputGroup>
          <InputGroup>
            <InputField placeholder='' />
            <InputLabel>Full Name</InputLabel>
          </InputGroup>
```

thats the result that I get the label is on the input text
[image]